# javascript - innerHTML in <span> in iframe wont change html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, innerhtml

I am trying to change HTML code within an IFrame (it's on the same domain), but for some reason, this line, wont change the html:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#weergave_afstand').innerHTML = afstand
```

the text it should modify is the following:

```
Afstand traject: <span id="weergave_afstand">200</span> km.
```

But for some reason, it doesn't.

When I use

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#weergave_afstand').html()
```

it reads the value (200) just fine...
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

innerHtml is not a jQuery function, it is [an HTMLElement Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp).
Usage --> http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

To write to the inner html using jquery you can use the same [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function which you used for read.

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#weergave_afstand').html(afstand);
```

Comment: I think `afstand` was a variable, not a string value.

Comment: wait a second... yes... you're trying to pass a string and not the variable

Comment: Sweet!! This works perfectly!
To be honest I didnt really know I was using jQuery, I got the function from somewhere here at stackoverflow I believe. But now it works, thank you very much!

Comment: No I cant... I still have to wait 1 minute... :(

Comment: innerHTML is not a function at all.

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML is not a jQuery method. You can change the innerHTML property by putting the value in the html() method like this:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#weergave_afstand').html("afstand");
```

Hope that helps!